# Ethernet Connection via Laptop to Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4, ethernet-port

I have been trying to design a project on my R-pi for months. I have been able to work of my R-pi from my home WiFi. However when I enter my Library's public network it cannot connect to the servers. This is why I want to connect my R-pi to my laptop over an Ethernet connection so it can use the Library's WiFi connection. I'm not sure if this is even possible as I am new to R-pi some any comments will be greatful.

**UPDATE** with info from comment:
My Laptop and R-pi have been connected over my WiFi connection allowing me to transfer PLC programs designed on my laptop to my R-pi. However when I move away from my home WiFi I have to change the WiFi on my R-pi all the time. So I am just wondering can I connect my R-pi to my laptop over an Ethernet cable.. No the laptop isn't able to see the server as it is on the R-pi and the laptop has no communication to it. Hence I want the Laptop to be able to communicate with the R-pi when the Laptop is connected to a public WiFi source.

Comment: Hello, welcome.  What is the actual question please - it's unclear?  What servers are you trying to connect to? Where are they located? Can your laptop see the servers when it's in the library?

Comment: Hi Mark, my Laptop and R-pi have been connected over my WiFi connection allowing me to transfer PLC programs designed on my laptop to my R-pi. However when I move away from my home WiFi I have to change the WiFi on my R-pi all the time. So I am just wondering can I connect my R-pi to my laptop over an Ethernet cable.. No the laptop isn't able to see the server as it is on the R-pi and the laptop has no communication to it. Hence I want the Laptop to be able to communicate with the R-pi when the Laptop is connected to a public WiFi source

Comment: your question is not about a Raspberry Pi at all ... your question is about your PC and how to configure it as a LAN gateway

Answer (score 2):

You would have to set static IP configurations for the ethernet connections on both your laptop and your Raspberry Pi 4. Here is an example configuration:

1. Set your laptop's ethernet connection IP as `192.168.7.1` and subnet mask to `255.255.255.0`
2. Set the Raspberry Pi's ethernet connection IP as `192.168.7.2`, subnet mask to `255.255.255.0` and default gateway to `192.168.7.1`(*your laptop's ethernet connection IP*)

**P.S:** You can change the `x` of the `192.168.x.y` addresses as long as it doesn't conflict with your other connections' IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to change the WiFi on the RasPi all the time. You can one time just add an additional `network {}` block to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with the settings of the Library's public network (country, ssid, psk). Then wpa_supplicant will connect to it automatically as soon as the RasPi is carried to the library.